# Call to undefined method (laravel 8) ao tentar dar update

Tags: php, laravel

como faz para iniciar o model com o id correspondente ao que eu quero para poder pegar o method dele para recriar a notificação?

exemplo quero pegar a winery com id 35 que vem na variável $winery_id e criar novamente a notificação com o relacionamento do mesmo.

Model de Notificação

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notification extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'pivot',
    ];
    protected $with = ['wineries:name,id', 'users:name,id'];
    public function wineries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Winery::class, 'rel_notifications_wineries', 'notification_id', 'winery_id');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'rel_notifications_users', 'notification_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

esse aqui e o controller que estou chamando pela rota

```
public function update(Request $request, $winery_id)
    {
        $request->only(['desc', 'name', 'story', 'winemaker', 'status']);
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'desc' => ['required'],
            'name' => ['required'],
            'story' => ['required'],
            'winemaker' => ['required'],
            'status' => ['required'],
        ]);

        try {
            $winery = Winery::findOrFail($winery_id);

            $winery->name = $request->name;
            $winery->status = $request->status;
            $winery->save();

            $winery = new Winery;
            $notification = Notification::whereHas('wineries', function($query) use ($winery_id){
                $query->where('winery_id', $winery_id);
            });
            if(!isset($notification->is_read)) {
                $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
                $notification = Notification::create();
                $winery->notifications()->attach($notification);
                $user->notificationsUser()->attach($notification);
            }

            foreach($validated['desc'] as $lang => $row){
                $wineryi18n = WineryI18n::where(['winery_id' => $winery_id, 'locale' => $lang])->firstOrFail();
                $wineryi18n->desc = $validated['desc'][$lang];
                $wineryi18n->story = $validated['story'][$lang];
                $wineryi18n->winemaker = $validated['winemaker'][$lang];
                $wineryi18n->save();
            }

            return response(['winery' => $winery]);

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'Forbidden', 'error' => $exception->getMessage()], 403);
        }
    }
```

este é o model de Winery

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Winery extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'region_id',
        'pivot',
    ];
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'address',
        'city',
        'zipcode',
        'region_id',
        'status',
        'since',
    ];
    protected $with = ['uploads', 'grapes'];

    protected $table = 'wineries';

    public function region()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Region::class, 'id', 'region_id');
    }
    public function winemaker()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(WineMaker::class, 'id', 'winemaker_id');
    }
    public function i18n()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(WineryI18n::class, 'winery_id', 'id');
    }
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'winery_id', 'id');
    }
    public function notification()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Winery::class, 'rel_notifications_wineries', 'winery_id', 'notification_id')->withPivot('type');
    }
    public function uploads()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Upload::class, 'rel_wineries_uploads', 'winery_id', 'upload_id')->withPivot('type');
    }
    public function grapes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Grape::class, 'rel_wineries_grapes', 'winery_id', 'grape_id');
    }
}
```

quando eu executo a rota ele da este error:

```
error: "Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Winery::notifications()"
status: "Forbidden"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método que retorna o relacionamento na classe Winery é `notification()`, mas você o utiliza chamando `notifications()` (no plural) dentro do Controller.

Tente alterar e veja se surte efeito.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: o que um caracter faz, não da pra fazer cansado mesmo... mas vlw mesmo sempre bom ter outros olhos pra perceber erros bobos msm.